# Which algorithm to use to identify clusters with a similar value?

Tags: regression, clustering, prediction, noise, pattern-recognition

Here, an example of my problem:
10000 observations of people with several features [age, gender, region, number of sons, ...] and a value to predict "income".
There is not a general relationship between features and income, therefore a normal regression has poor results.
Nevertheless, I want to identify specific patterns where this relationship exists. For instance:
[young, woman, 2 son] -> high income
[young, man] -> small income
...

Maybe doing a clustering on the features, and then a regression on each cluster?
Or pattern recognition? topic modeling?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression). The target variable (income) is divided into discrete groups where the relative ordering between different groups is preserved (low, middle, high).

Binning a continuous variable as the advantage of better handling noisy data.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but it is not always the case. Because even if I make bins of the target variable, there can be some patterns in the features that lead to a clear "income", while the rest is noisy. e.g. [young, man] -> "small income", but the other values of all the features are just noisy.

Answer (score 1):

Plot the distribution of income (histogram) and see if you see clusters there (i.e. if it is a Gaussian mixture) and if so, tray to do your regression for each cluster there and see if it works.

Example: If you want to predict recruitment based on CV, then for a normal office job your target is almost regardless of input as many people with many background can do that but for a technical expert position you see more correlation between features and target. Might happen in your data as well.

The more precise way to do this is actually to [discritize your numeric features](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/93-2/Papers/022.pdf) and one-hot-encode all the features. Then if the correlation between target and only some values of features exist, then you will be able to capture it.